# Coffee-Script Nodejs and Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, coffeescript, express, mongoose

Hey all trying to play with nodejs MVC using express and mongoose.

I have the following code:

```
mongoose = require 'mongoose'
Schema = mongoose.Schema
mongoose.connect 'mongodb://localhost/quotes'

Quote = new Schema()

Quote.add {
  quote : { type: String, required: true}
  , rank  : Number
}

quote = new mongoose.model 'Quote', Quote


module.exports = 

  index: (req,res, next) ->
    quote.find {}, (err,docs) ->
      res.render docs
```

When I go to run the server, I receive the following:

```
Server started on port 3000

module.js:311
    throw err;
          ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Quote' of undefined
    at new <anonymous> (/Users ....
```

I can't work out why it keeps throwing the undefined error.

**EDIT:**

Here is the compiled JS

```
var Quote, Schema, mongoose, quote;

mongoose = require('mongoose');

Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/quotes');

Quote = new Schema();

Quote.add({
  quote: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  rank: Number
});

quote = new mongoose.model('Quote', Quote);

module.exports = {
  index: function(req, res, next) {
    return quote.find({}, function(err, docs) {
      return res.render(docs);
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: What does generated javascript look like?

Comment: I've added to the question for you :o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `mongoose.model` is not a constructor. It's been a while since I've used mongoose, but I don't remember `Schema.add` either, the fields should be passed to the constructor call. So it would look like this:

```
Quote = new Schema
    quote : { type: String, required: true }
    rank  : Number

quote = mongoose.model 'Quote', Quote
```

---

*edit*: `Schema.add` is fine, it's actually called from the constructor. It's just briefly mentioned in the docs.

Comment: Thanks. the passing of new was what the problem was. :D